# Small Business Server 2011, why does it take so long to load?

Tags: time, boot, bootloader, small-business-server

I have in my company, SBS 2011, on a mother board that handles Dual Xeon Quad Core 3.2 Ghz processors (X5492), 16GB of ram, 500GB main drive, 1 TB raid, and a gigabit network...

The administrator says it takes between 10 to 15 minutes to boot, and fully load for functionality. Can someone here explain why?

I use to be an administrator at other companies and entities, including at home where I am running OS X Server.

OS X Server takes less than 5 minutes to load on a Mac Mini maxed out.  Why is Windows SBS 2011 being on a vastly more expandable and more robust hardware platform (Xeon Processors compared to i5)...

My administrator tells me it's complex and I won't understand. I say nuts to that, but I let them think they know more than me.

I just can't agree that SBS 2011 is so complex of an OS that it takes more time to start up everything than it does to make a plate of nachos from scratch (including frying the chips yourself).

Can someone explain to me why it takes so long? All we are doing using it for a file sharing and email server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that it's loading a lot of services like Exchange, SQL Server, etc. that are considerably more bloated than Mac/Linux counterparts such as MySQL.

Also, NTFS is supposed to be an error-resistant journaling filesystem like the Mac and Linux, BUT it is much more prone to corruption due to abrupt power-off shutdowns than Mac/Linux AND the filesystem check and cleanup on reboot takes an incredible amount of time compared to Mac/Linux.

Comment: $20k to get this system up and running, and its still nothing better than an expensive anchor... I really wish they did research before going into it head first.